# How do I access iframe contents with in another iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page

```
<div id="editForm_container">
<form id="imageForm" name="imageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hiddenFrame" method="post" action="test.php">                   

    <label><strong>File Name</strong></label>
    <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_image" id="submit_image" />

</form>
<iframe id="hiddenFrame" name="hiddenFrame"></iframe>
```

and I load this page to **another iframe located in another page** and I wrote this in my js file

```
$("#imageFrame").load(function(){

this.imageFramecontent = $("#imageFrame").contents();
this.imageFramefields.fileField = this.imageFramecontent.find( ":input[ name = 'fileupload' ]" );
this.imageFrameform = this.imageFramecontent.find( "form#imageForm" );
this.hiddenFrame = this.imageFramecontent.find("iframe#hiddenFrame");

this.imageFramefields.fileField.change(function(){

    self.imageFrameform.submit();
    self.hiddenFrame.load(function(){

        alert(self.hiddenFrame.contents().html());
    });                     
});
```

This returns a blank alert. How do I get the **#hiddenFrame contents**?

Comment: are all your iframes loaded under the same domain? have you noticed any error in javascript console?

Comment: Yes on same domain . Console return no error

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Please help on this issue if have solution...Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. The `.contents()` method returns a set of DOM elements so you need to specify what element you want to return the html for. So you'd need a line like this :

```
hiddenFrame.contents().find('html').html();
```

I couldn't quite get a sample running off the code you supplied above, but I managed to get it working with the following tweaks :

```
$("#imageFrame").load(function(){

    imageFramecontent = $("#imageFrame").contents();
    imageFrameupload = imageFramecontent.find( ":input[ name = 'fileupload' ]" );
    imageFrameform = imageFramecontent.find( "form#imageForm" );
    hiddenFrame = imageFramecontent.find("iframe#hiddenFrame");

    imageFrameupload.change(function(){

        hiddenFrame.load(function(){

            alert(hiddenFrame.contents().find('html').html());

        }); 
        imageFrameform.submit();

    });
});
```

Comment: You are a Genius Goran and Thank you for your help

Your solution has solved many issues.Thank you